# Best way to search 2d Array board

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array for a game of a 9x9 board for Gomoku. I want to scan the board as quickly and efficiently as possible to find pieces. I need to check if their is a row/col/diagonal of X amount of whites/blacks.

Is the best way just to use a for-loop or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to use 2 nested for loops, one for width and other for height. You can use a single for loop that iterates 81 times, but this is the same but complicated.

Comment: I agree with @Kilanny, I created a chess game that used a 2d array, and that was the most efficient way that I found to iterate through the board.

Comment: It depends on how you track data on your board.  You aren't rule-bound to do a full loop through the whole board, but you'll have to track some metadata about positions of things if you want optimization.  If you're only tracking 9x9 cells, I don't really see the point and I think you're prematurely optimizing.

Comment: It's the easiest way, but not the fastest. Since you only have only an 9 x 9 array, I would stick at this solution. Maybe even more solid one: Have a loop iterating over every position and every direction and look, if the contained positions satisfy your condition.

Comment: The best way to scan the array in a efficient way is to worry about the data structure you're going to use to represent the game. For example, instead of using char[][] for represent the game, you can create a class representing your row/col cell. There will be a value to represent the color ('w' or 'b'), there will be a counter of how many black in that row, another counter of how many black in the column (the same for white). I'm not sure if it'll be better but I think it's a good shot.

Comment: You could flatten the array ( because it is just 9x9 ) into 1x81 and perform binary search on it. java.util.Arrays has a binary [search](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)) - O( logn)

Comment: You can change slightly what I said. You can use a char[][], but use a blackRowCounter[] for representing the number of black in a row. Another blackColCounter[] for the number of black in a column, and so on. So, when you're going to count the number of white in a row R, you do the math: rowNumber - blackRowCounter[R]. And that's O(1). That's better than looping through 9 cels to count the number of white in a row and 9 through 9 cels to count the number of white in a column.

Answer (score 0):

This usually depends on the game, how many pieces there are vs cells on the board. If your game had a 1000x1000 board and only 10 pieces it would be terrible to use a nested loop to find them (sparse array). It would be better to track the board pieces using a dedicated structure like a list or hashmap.
But in your case a nested loop + 2d array is a good solution. The 2d array also has the benefit of quick random access.